# Parse this JSON in java?

Tags: java, json

I have this JSONObject which is returned as response from a 3rd party API.

```
[
[
    {
        "msg": "hi",
        "uuid": "fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815"
    },
    {
        "msg": "hihe",
        "uuid": "fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815"
    }
],
14281343855179004,
14281349424008428
]
```

How can I parse this?

This is what I get

```
[[{"msg":"hi","uuid":"fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815"},{"msg":"hihe","uuid":"fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815"}],14281343855179005,14281349424008427]
```

My Code

```
  try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(message.toString());

                JSONObject sys  = reader.getJSONObject("uuid");
                String msg = sys.getString("msg");
                System.out.println(msg);



            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Could you show us your code

Comment: you could use a search engine and look for a java library which will do the job for you. there are several good libraries you could include in your project.

Comment: @Juxhin updated the question please check

Comment: Your output doesn't match with code you posted. Your code would generate exceptions since you want to read array as object, or String as object. Remember: arrays start with `[`, objects start with `{`.

Comment: What do think your code should do and why do you think so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray("[[{\"msg\":\"hi\",\"uuid\":\"fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815\"},{\"msg\":\"hihe\",\"uuid\":\"fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815\"}],14281343855179005,14281349424008427]");
JSONArray arr  = json.getJSONArray(0);

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    String message = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("msg");
    String uuid    = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("uuid");
    System.out.println("message : "+message);
    System.out.println("uuid    : "+uuid);
}
```

Output :

```
message : hi
uuid    : fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815
message : hihe
uuid    : fc8c5dd3-d46c-4945-894d-6160f830d815
```

Answer (score 1):

You could directly use `JSONArray` instead of `JSONObject`

```
  public static void parseJson(String message) {
    try {
      JSONArray json = new JSONArray(message);    
      JSONArray elemArr = json.getJSONArray(0);

      for (int i = 0; i < elemArr.length(); i++) {
        String msg = elemArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("msg");
        System.out.println("msg=" + msg);
        String uuid = elemArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("uuid");
        System.out.println("uuid=" + uuid);        
      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Kindly remove the comments then :p

Answer (score 0):

GSON is good example to convert Json to Java objects.

http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/06/17/google-gson-tutorial-convert-java-object-to-from-json/

Thanks,
Pavan

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)